# Error in setting up Jersey

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey

i am trying to build an application using spring boot. i am trying to configure jersy .

```
public class DemoApplication{

private static class Configuration extends AbstractApplicationConfiguration { }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Configuration.class, args);
}
}




@Configuration
@Import({ WebXmlConfiguration.class})
@ImportResource({ "classpath*:META-INF/spring/appContext.xml" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, 
FlywayAutoConfiguration.class,
    SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class AbstractApplicationConfiguration {

}





@Configuration
public class WebXmlConfiguration {


@Bean
public Filter springSecurityFilterChain() {
    return new DelegatingFilterProxy();
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean jersey() {
    System.out.println("initalized jersey");
    Servlet jerseyServlet = new SpringServlet();
    try{

 System.out.println(jerseyServlet.getServletConfig().getServletName());
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ServletRegistrationBean jerseyServletRegistration = new 
ServletRegistrationBean();
    jerseyServletRegistration.setServlet(jerseyServlet);
    jerseyServletRegistration.addUrlMappings("/*");
    jerseyServletRegistration.setName("jersey-servlet");
    jerseyServletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);


 jerseyServletRegistration 
.addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
    jerseyServletRegistration.addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters",
            ResponseCorsFilter.class.getName());
    jerseyServletRegistration.addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.feature.DisableWADL", "true");
    System.out.println("end of spring config");
    // debugging for development:
    // jerseyServletRegistration.addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters",
    // LoggingFilter.class.getName());
    return jerseyServletRegistration;
}


}
```

when i run this code i get an error saying " The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes". the log is shared with below. and whenever i hit an api the same error appears " The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes."

```
2017-06-18 21:10:17.738  INFO 15676 --- [           main] com.praveen.praveen.PraveenApplication   : Starting PraveenApplication on praveen-PC with PID 15676 (started by praveen in C:\Users\praveen\Desktop\New folder\praveen\praveen)
2017-06-18 21:10:17.754  INFO 15676 --- [           main] com.praveen.praveen.PraveenApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-06-18 21:10:17.953  INFO 15676 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@105fece7: startup date [Sun Jun 18 21:10:17 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-18 21:10:23.041  INFO 15676 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-06-18 21:10:23.081  INFO 15676 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-06-18 21:10:23.084  INFO 15676 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
2017-06-18 21:10:23.359  INFO 15676 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-06-18 21:10:23.360  INFO 15676 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5418 ms
initalized jersey
end of spring config
2017-06-18 21:10:23.783  INFO 15676 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-18 21:10:23.784  INFO 15676 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-18 21:10:23.784  INFO 15676 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-18 21:10:23.784  INFO 15676 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-18 21:10:23.786  INFO 15676 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2017-06-18 21:10:23.786  INFO 15676 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'jersey-servlet' to [/*]
2017-06-18 21:10:23.788  INFO 15676 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-06-18 21:10:24.389  INFO 15676 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@105fece7: startup date [Sun Jun 18 21:10:17 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-18 21:10:24.537  INFO 15676 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-06-18 21:10:24.541  INFO 15676 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-06-18 21:10:24.640  INFO 15676 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-06-18 21:10:24.642  INFO 15676 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-06-18 21:10:24.750  INFO 15676 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-06-18 21:10:25.055  INFO 15676 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-06-18 21:10:25.216  INFO 15676 --- [           main] c.s.j.s.s.c.servlet.SpringServlet        : Using default applicationContext
2017-06-18 21:10:25.220  INFO 15676 --- [           main] c.s.j.s.i.a.WebApplicationImpl           : Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.17 01/17/2013 03:31 PM'
2017-06-18 21:10:25.612 ERROR 15676 --- [           main] c.s.j.s.i.a.RootResourceUriRules         : The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
2017-06-18 21:10:25.620 ERROR 15676 --- [           main] c.s.j.s.s.c.servlet.SpringServlet        : Exception occurred when intialization

com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99) ~[jersey-server-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1331) ~[jersey-server-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:168) ~[jersey-server-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:774) ~[jersey-server-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:770) ~[jersey-server-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193) ~[jersey-core-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770) ~[jersey-server-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.initiate(SpringServlet.java:117) ~[jersey-spring-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319) [jersey-servlet-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605) [jersey-servlet-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210) [jersey-servlet-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374) [jersey-servlet-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557) [jersey-servlet-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:992) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.deferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:78) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.startConnector(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:273) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:196) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at com.praveen.praveen.PraveenApplication.main(PraveenApplication.java:15) [bin/:na]

2017-06-18 21:10:25.621 ERROR 15676 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : StandardWrapper.Throwable

com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99) ~[jersey-server-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1331) ~[jersey-server-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:168) ~[jersey-server-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:774) ~[jersey-server-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:770) ~[jersey-server-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193) ~[jersey-core-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770) ~[jersey-server-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.initiate(SpringServlet.java:117) ~[jersey-spring-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319) ~[jersey-servlet-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605) ~[jersey-servlet-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210) ~[jersey-servlet-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374) ~[jersey-servlet-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557) ~[jersey-servlet-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:992) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.deferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:78) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.startConnector(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:273) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:196) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at com.praveen.praveen.PraveenApplication.main(PraveenApplication.java:15) [bin/:na]

2017-06-18 21:10:25.622 ERROR 15676 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Servlet [jersey-servlet] in web application [] threw load() exception

com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99) ~[jersey-server-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1331) ~[jersey-server-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:168) ~[jersey-server-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:774) ~[jersey-server-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:770) ~[jersey-server-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193) ~[jersey-core-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770) ~[jersey-server-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.initiate(SpringServlet.java:117) ~[jersey-spring-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319) ~[jersey-servlet-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605) ~[jersey-servlet-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210) ~[jersey-servlet-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374) ~[jersey-servlet-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557) ~[jersey-servlet-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:992) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.deferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:78) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.startConnector(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:273) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:196) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at com.praveen.praveen.PraveenApplication.main(PraveenApplication.java:15) [bin/:na]

2017-06-18 21:10:25.637  INFO 15676 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-06-18 21:10:25.645  INFO 15676 --- [           main] com.praveen.praveen.PraveenApplication   : Started PraveenApplication in 9.426 seconds (JVM running for 11.567)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use Jersey 1.x with Spring Boot?

Comment: @peeskillet i am comfortable with jersey annotations. is there any better way please suggest me

Comment: My point is that you are using Jersey _version_ 1.x, when you should be using 2.x, which is better integrated with Spring Boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Configuration Class

```
@Configuration
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
           register(JerseyController.class);
       }
   }
```

This JerseyController Class is the one that will have all the rest ends

```
@Component
@Path("/jersey")
public class JerseyController {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String health() {
        System.out.println("Here");
        return "Jersey: Up and Running!";
    }
}
```

Hope this helps (note : donot forget to add the jersey dependency for Spring boot)

Comment: Thanks for the response, Just one more question,i need to register each and every Controller classes. say if i have 10 controller classes i need to register all of them? or can i use wild card that can get all the classes ??

Comment: you can do that or have a seperate class thats binds to these classes and then do the same above

Comment: You could inject a ListableBeanFactory into your JerseyConfig and then add all beans which have a Path annotation i.e. 

```public JerseyConfig(ListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        beanFactory.getBeansWithAnnotation(Path.class).values().forEach(this::register);
```

Comment: I solved the problem by add the below line of code in my WebXmlConfiguration class
         jerseyServletRegistration
    .addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", 
    "com.example.mypackage");