# Jersey and Springboot application throws java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, filter, jersey

Trying to create a Spring-boot applicaiton with Jersey to respond to REST calls. The code is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44616721/error-in-setting-up-jersey). The application starts up successfully but when a REST call is there is an infinite loop as seen in logs and after some time an exception is thrown.

appContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="org.ideoholic" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- <mvc:annotation-driven /> -->
</beans>
```

Java configuration code:

```
@Configuration
@Import({ WebXmlConfiguration.class })
@ImportResource({ "classpath*:appContext.xml" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

}


@Configuration
@Profile("basicauth")
public class WebXmlConfiguration {

@Bean
public Filter springSecurityFilterChain() {
    return new DelegatingFilterProxy();
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<Servlet> jersey() {
    Servlet jerseyServlet = new SpringServlet();
    ServletRegistrationBean<Servlet> jerseyServletRegistration = new ServletRegistrationBean<Servlet>();

    jerseyServletRegistration.setServlet(jerseyServlet);
    jerseyServletRegistration.addUrlMappings("/rest/v1/*");
    jerseyServletRegistration.setName("jersey-servlet");
    jerseyServletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    jerseyServletRegistration.addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
    jerseyServletRegistration.addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.feature.DisableWADL", "true");
    jerseyServletRegistration.addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "org.ideoholic");
    return jerseyServletRegistration;
  }

}


@SpringBootApplication
public class RestSpringApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(RestSpringApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            SpringApplication.run(ApplicationConfiguration.class, args);
    }
}
```

The error as seen in the log is an infinite loop DelegatingFilterProxy

```
ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
```

The complete code is available on [Github](https://github.com/reehanlalkhan/RESTfulExample)

Comment: what happens when you remove `springSecurityFilterChain()`?

Comment: You have a delegating fitler which delegates to itself again and again and again.

Comment: Also you are using Jersey and Spring Boot then why are you working around Spring Boot (it will autoconfigure jersey as well as Spring Security?).

Comment: If `springSecurityFilterChain()` is removed it works. Thank you.
But as the code will grow will need to add delegating filters. Will look it up on how to configure filters.
Also not sure why this code is `working around Spring Boot`. It would be great if Spring took up all the boilerplate handling, not sure how to configure that. Any help in this regards will be highly appreciated.
Thank you @user7294900 and @m-Deinum for your inputs. Really helpful and addressed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `springSecurityFilterChain()`, if you need to add filters use [@WebFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html)

> Annotation used to declare a servlet filter.